# What are the properties of primes with a given (chosen) pair of last digits?

Tags: number-theory

Let's take an example of primes which end with the last digits 11. Let's consider the two forms (6k+1) and (6k-1) separately. We then have:

(6k-1)=(11,311,911,1511,1811,2111,2411,2711,3011,3911,4211,5711...)
and
(6k+1)=(211,811,2011,2311,3511,4111,5011,6211,7411,8011,8300,9511...)

We notice that the smallest gap between two consecutive primes is 300. Other consecutive gaps are a multiple of 300 in both groups.
What can we say about the properties of a subset of primes? Can a subset of primes ( with same last two digits or same last 3 or 4 or n digits ) obey the same rules and theorems derived for the (entire) set of primes?
If one were looking for a prime, wouldn't be easier to fix the last two digits and then just increment the search by 300 and test for primality? How about fixing the last 10 or 100 digits, the smaller gap between two consecutive primes will no longer be 300, it will be much bigger (as a simple numerical check can show).
I welcome any thought on the matter.

Comment: Well, [Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) assures us that, so long as your chosen last two digits are prime to $10$, there are infinitely many primes.  Moreover, the probability (suitably defined) that a randomly chosen prime ends with your desired two digits is $\frac 1{\varphi(100)}=\frac 1{40}$.  That's something!

Comment: Surely the gap between such primes must be both a multiple of $6$, and a multiple of $100$, i.e. a multiple of $\mathrm{lcm} (6,100)=300$.

Comment: @lulu, how about counting them. is there a known expression for the number of such primes ( with a given last two digits ) below a given N. I suppose we can't use Pi(x) in this case.

Comment: Well, roughly speaking it's the same formula times $\frac 1{40}$.  See [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/the-prime-number-theorem-in-arithmetic-progressions-and-dueling-conspiracies/) for a discussion.